# premultiplied alpha

Tags: java, android, canvas, bitmap

Проблемы с цветом при рисовке bitmap в Canvas.

Так же Когда применяю цветовой фильтр к Bitmap появляются черная обводка по бокам у изображений с прозрачностью.  Я знаю что это происходит из за так называемого premultiplied режима, но как это можно обойти продолжая использовать Canvas? Или поможет только использование OpenGL?
Посмотрел это видео : youtube.com/watch?v=-dK71TVrBLM.

Если я правильно понял, данного эффекта можно избежать разделив все каналы на alpha значение (перед рисованием самого Bitmap?), вопрос только правильно ли я все понял и поможет ли это в данном конкретном случае? 
Вот пара иллюстраций: Первая о том, что происходит при применении colorfilter.(Никакой коррекции цвета\альфы, просто применение фильтра).

[image: После\До]

Вторая. Простая рисовка градиента без каких либо преобразований. 
Вот как картинка выглядит в фотошопе (с лева) - по всему изображению равные значения цвета.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После рисовки - в центре более менее - тот изначальный цвет. Далее потихоньку начинает исчезать красный ( хотя в изначальным варианте цветовых градаций нет ) после чего и вовсе исчезает, а синий, внезапно вылезает еще сильнее. Опять же получается та же темная граница по радиусу, только малозаметная.

[Код](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35785060/bitmap-transparens-glow-effect):

```
class DrawView extends View {

  Paint paint;
  Bitmap bitmap;
  Rect rect;

    float[] cmData = new float[]{
            1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
            0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
            0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
            0, 0, 0, 1, 0};

    ColorMatrix cm;
    ColorFilter filter;
    Bitmap icon;

  public DrawView(Context context) {
    super(context);

    rect  = new Rect(0,0,200,200);

    paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);

    icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);

    cm = new ColorMatrix(cmData);

    filter = new ColorMatrixColorFilter(cm);

  }

  @Override
  protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.drawARGB(80, 102, 204, 255);

    canvas.translate(100, 100);

    canvas.save();

    canvas.translate(220, 0);
    canvas.drawBitmap(icon, null, rect, paint);
    canvas.restore();


    paint.setColorFilter(filter);
    canvas.translate(0, 300);

    canvas.save();

    canvas.translate(220, 0);
    canvas.drawBitmap(icon, null, rect, paint);
    canvas.restore();
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Деление на альфу может помочь, но если в используете глубину в 8 бит, то при делении вы потеряете часть информации. Я думаю вы это видите в вашем втором случае.

Чтобы лучше понять зачем нужно преумножения прозрачности необходимо ознакомится с альфа-смешиванием: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_compositing

Альфа-смешивание имеет довольно сложную формулу:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но если цвет преумножен на прозрачность то формула становится на много проще:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Для получение лучше результата могу посоветовать вам найти изображение без преумноженной прозрачности или смешивать картинку с фоном используя формулу рассчитанную на работу с преумноженной прозрачностью. Также если вы накладываете какие-либо фильтры, необходимо быть уверенными, что они правильно обрабатывают этот случай.